# How get value from current controller?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

if I call the POST action method I want to get the data from the files-object of my GET action method.

```cs
public class UploadController:Controller {

    public IActionResult Index(){
        // Here is some code
        return View(files);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(IFormFile importFile){
    {
        // Here I want to work with data from the files object of my Index() method above
        return View("Index", newFiles);
    }
}
```

My View looks like this:

```
@using MVC-project.Models
@model UploadViewModel

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (string file in Model.FileName )
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@file</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadFile", new { fileName = file })</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>



@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "upldFrm", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="file" class=" form-control" name="importFile" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="submit" name="filesubmit" value="Upload" />
        </div>
    </div>

}

// Here is some code and if-case for processing after the POST submit
```

How can I use the data from the files object of my GET Index() action method in my POST Index method?

Comment: HTTP is stateless. Each request will have a new instance of the controller. Though both actions could call the same private method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass data between Actions in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759388/pass-data-between-actions-in-mvc)

Comment: @MiladDastanZand Yes and No :D 
How can use keep and peek in my razor code to keep my ViewModel? 
Maybe there is another way outside of razor to keep and peek the ViewModel

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do this. You could put the files in a view data dictionary in the get controller.

```
ViewData["Files"] = files
```

Then retrieve it from your post.

```
var files = ViewData["Files"]
```

You could also pass the files to a view model in your get controller, send it to your view. Then pass it to the post action when you submit the form on the view.

```
public class ViewModel {
     public string Files {get; set;}
     public IFormFile File {get; set;} 
} 


[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index(){
    var viewModel = new ViewModel 
    {
        Files = files
    };
    return View(viewModel);
} 

[HttpPost] 
public IActionResult Index(ViewModel viewModel){
.... 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your solution, but my ViewModel parameter in the POST action is empty... :(

Comment: @Christian01 How are you binding it in your view? Please share the view

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example to get the data before the post action.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  HttpResponseMessage response =GlobalVariables.webApiClient.GetAsync("Tbl_Books/"+ id.ToString()).Result;

  return View(response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Books>().Result);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Books newbook)
{

  HttpResponseMessage response =GlobalVariables.webApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Tbl_Books", newbook).Result;
            
  HttpResponseMessage response = 
  GlobalVariables.webApiClient.PutAsJsonAsync("Tbl_Books/" + newbook.BookId, newbook).Result;

  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here I will get the data from my get API method and this data is passed to the post view[HttpPost] and then post or put action can be performed.